# Couch db bulk operations

Tags: couchdb, conflict, ektorp, bulk-operations

So I've  been trying to move data from one database to another. I've already move them but I need to clear the documents which I've already moved from the old database. I've been using ektorp's execute bulk to perform bulk operations. But for some reason I keep getting `document update conflict` when I try to delete bulk by inserting `_deleted`.
I might be doing it wrong, here is what I did.

1. Fetch by bulk with `include docs`. (For some reason, this doesn't work with just `id` and `rev`.)
2. Then include the _deleted field to each document.
3. Post using `executebulk`.

It works for some documents but keeps getting document update conflict for some documents.

Any solution/suggestions please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the preferred way of deleting docs in bulk:

```
List<Object> bulkDocs = ...
MyClass toBeDeleted = ...

bulkDocs.add(BulkDeleteDocument.of(toBeDeleted));

db.executeBulk(bulkDocs);
```

Comment: Thanks Henrik! Either way, it looks like we have to include the documents as well even for deleting. I was hoping maybe if we supply only the id and rev, it should also work.

Comment: The resulting json document will only contain the id, rev and _deleted fields

Comment: Oh...you mean the bulkDocs or the resultant document after deletion.. because Im trying to delete in huge numbers and querying with http client so if I do include docs, it just hurts the performance real bad... so was looking for a way to minimise the response and request payloads.... thanks for the info anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a way to delete/update docs in bulk and you don't need to necessarily implement it in your own software, you can use the great couchapp at:

https://github.com/harthur/costco

You need to upload it to your own server with a [couchapp deployment tool](https://www.smileupps.com/smileupps-deployment-tools), and use a function like

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.istodelete)  // replace this or remove to delete all docs
        return null;
}
```

Read [instructions](https://github.com/harthur/costco) and [examples](http://harthur.github.io/costco/)